# How to connect to a paired Bluetooth device in a List View by clicking the item

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Alright so currently my app turns on bluetooth on my device and then lists all paired devices in a List View. I am trying to make it so when the item in the list view is clicked it will connect to the device (primarily for bluetooth speakers). Below i have listed my main java file with all the code that runs my app. If anyone could get me going in the right direction id appreciate it. Also this is my first project working with bluetooth.

```
package com.applie.itchaboynathan.appv2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.UUID;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import java.util.Set;
import android.os.Handler;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static SeekBar seek_bar;
    private static TextView text_view;
    private BluetoothAdapter BA;
    private Set<BluetoothDevice>pairedDevices;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    ListView lv;
    ImageView iv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        volumeBar();
        BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.deviceList);
        iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgConnection);

        //define menu button
        ImageButton menubutton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibtnMenu);
        //enables the button to show a menu
        menubutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {
            @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                    final PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getApplicationContext(),v);

                    popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.main_menu);
                popupMenu.show();


                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.connect:
                            //code for connect item
                            //Delay so the list creates
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run(){
                                    list();
                                    visible();
                                    iv.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_checked);
                                }
                            }, 4200);
                            turnOn();

                            return true;
                        case R.id.disconnect:
                            //code for music item
                            turnOff();
                            iv.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_disconnected);
                            listClear();
                            return true;
                        case R.id.music:
                            //code for music item
                            return true;
                        case R.id.play:
                            //code for play item
                            return true;
                        case R.id.pause:
                            //code for pause item

                            return true;

                    }
                    return false;
                }
                });
        }
    });//end of button

}
    //bluettoth enabler
    public void turnOn(){
        if (!BA.isEnabled()) {
            Intent turnOn = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(turnOn, 0);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Turned on",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    //bluetooth disable
    public void turnOff(){
        BA.disable();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Turned off" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public  void visible(){
        Intent getVisible = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        startActivityForResult(getVisible, 0);
    }

    public void listClear(){
        lv.setAdapter(null);
    }
    public void list(){
        pairedDevices = BA.getBondedDevices();

        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

        for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices) list.add(bt.getName());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Showing Paired Devices",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new  ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    //volume bar code
    public void volumeBar(){
        seek_bar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        text_view =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtVolumeLvl);
        text_view.setText("Volume : " + seek_bar.getProgress() + " % ");

        seek_bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
            int progress_value;
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                progress_value = progress;
                text_view.setText("Volume : " + progress +  " % ");


            }


            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                text_view.setText("Volume : " + progress_value + " % ");

            }
        }
        );
    }
    //end volume bar

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have use `BluetoothSocket`for connecting bluetooth.

use the below code to connect.

```
 private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdarpter;
 private BluetoothSocket mBtSocket;
 private BluetoothDevice mBTDevice;
 private static final UUID SPP_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
 ..
 ..
 private boolean connectToDevice(String iAdress) {
    try {
        if(mBluetoothAdarpter == null) mBluetoothAdarpter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mBTDevice = mBluetoothAdarpter.getRemoteDevice(iAdress);
        mBtSocket = mBTDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SPP_UUID);
        mBtSocket.connect();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: and would i just call the connectToDevice method in an onclickeventlistener for the list view? also IOException and SPP_UUID is throwing and error

Comment: you need to pass bluetooth uuid there, i edited my answer see

Comment: alright so if i then make the clicklistener for the listview i would put that method into it so itd run that method when i clicked an item ?

Comment: exactly,  whenever you want to connect to bluetooth call that method by passing mac address of device as parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
          ArrayList list = new ArrayList();         
          public void list(){
                    pairedDevices = BA.getBondedDevices();               

                for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices) list.add(bt.getName());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Showing Paired Devices",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                final ArrayAdapter adapter = new  ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

               lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener () {
               @Override
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                  String selected = list.get(position);
                  for (Iterator<BluetoothDevice> it = pairedDevices.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                      BluetoothDevice bt = it.next();
                      if (bt.getName().equals(selected){
                      //connect to device
                      }                       
                  }
              });
          }
```